# how i can access all table from paginated table

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatable, paging

I have a paginated table. It's being built dynamically based on the results of a database call. I should write script code to affect all rows in table, I need to loop through all of the table rows, but it seems like I'm only able to iterate over the current rows that are visible on-screen, due to the pagination. So basically I may have 100 rows, but its only showing me rows 1-10 due to the pagination, which is expceted. But when i try to loop through the table contents, it only iterates through rows 1-10, instead of all 100 rows. Are there any API's or settings that will allow me to access all the rows?

```
$("#tableId").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function (index) { //?
        if (index !== 0) {
            $row = $(this);
            var id = $row.find("td:first").text();
           // some script codes...
```

Comment: You already have all data, since you crated a table with pages. Why do you want to read it again?

Comment: i try to write script code in other html page. My script codes affects all table rows but i can access just 10 rows from table.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Maybe you can add some code to a kind of `change page` event, meaning that everytime the page is changed, you run your code that will change the visible rows.

Comment: What I want to do is to have access to all the table elements in the first page or in the fifth page(nth page), not just the elements of the page I am on.